# Header appear on scroll does not work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, header

I am having a struggle with a header bar that appears on scrolling.
On desktop it works fine, but on mobile it does not fade in.

Here is my code.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $( "#navbar" ).fadeIn();
    } else {
        console.log('there');
        $( "#navbar" ).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Also a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rvovapxk/

Comment: Does not work means ?

Comment: It doesn't fade in on mobile, but it does fade on desktop. Thanks for the mention; i'll edit it.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com